# How do i correctly use 2 chains next to eachother in constraintLayout (android) without overlay of the chains when views grow bigger?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've been struggling with this for days now. Its probably possible without constraintLayout to get this done, but i'm would really like it to be done with constraintLayout.

I have 6 views next to eachother. 4 on the left side, 2 on the right, but at the same height. 
Those 2 on the left, they don't change width and they should be on the right always. 
Those 4 on the right change sizes and, more important, sometimes not all 4 views wil show up. 
I cant chain the six of them of course, because then, if there are only 2 tags on the left side, my 2 views on the right will move to the left.

My best attempt was chaining the 4 views on the left. And chaining the 2 views on the right. That works perfectly fine, except! when there is a larger view on the right, then these 4 views will overlay the 2 views on the right. But, whenever i make a constraint to make sure the 4 views will NOT overlay my right views, android thinks i'm chaining 6 views and i get the problem above.

Well, anyone who knows a fine trick to solve this? Its really a big puzzle for me.

This is how it should look:

[image]

How i want it to look (a bit like) so always a margin between the 4th and 5th view.

And here's the code i used:
(i have been struggling though and tried a lot of things like guidelines and barriers, so it's certainly nog yet clean and nice coding)

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    style="@style/helveticaRoman15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="1,7 km" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freeKm"
    style="@style/helveticaRoman15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minWidth="82dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/resource_view_free_km"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/distance"
    tools:text="100 vrije km" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    style="@style/helveticaRoman15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newIndicator"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="50dp"
    tools:text="bouwjaar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newIndicator"
    style="@style/helveticaMedium15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neu_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/resource_view_free_km"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    tools:text="nieuw" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="start"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="thumbImage, numberOfBookings"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb"
    android:tint="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/numberOfBookings"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/distance" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberOfBookings"
    style="@style/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_textview"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/distance"
    tools:text="100%" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="82dp" />
```

Comment: Hi and welcome... Please see how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you, is this a better question now?

Comment: Did you actually name the parent layout "parent"?  If not, you don't need the id tag for parent. Instead of this: app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent", use this: app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent". Also, the barrier on its own will do nothing, unless you constrain that to the guideline. I would also suggest using percentages instead of hardcoded values and horizontal/vertical biases.

Comment: hi thx, no, offcours it should have been just "parent". And yes, i mostly use percentages in my guidelines.  I will work on this the coming days and will try to constrain that barrier as you say. I'm not very confident that that will do the tric. I might end up using linear layouts anyway with the tags embedded in them.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed quite a bit now to get what i want. @NikosHidalgo thanks for the suggestion about the barrier/guideline. I'll put my code underneath. Unfortunately i do not jet really understand what i did, but it looks good.... – Titei 6 mins ago

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!--tag1-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/freeKm"
    tools:text="1,7 km" />

<!--tag2-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freeKm"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxWidth="95dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="100 vrije km" />

<!--tag3-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newIndicator"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/freeKm"
    tools:text="plaatsnaam" />

<!--tag4-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_car_location"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neu_bold"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/resource_view_free_km"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/yearOfConstruction"
    tools:text="nieuw" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="start"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="distance, freeKm, yearOfConstruction, newIndicator"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thumbImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline" />

<!--end image-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
    android:tint="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/distance"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/numberOfBookings"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/distance" />

<!-- end view-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberOfBookings"
    style="@style/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_textview"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/freeKm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/freeKm"
    tools:text="100%" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="85dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```